# A required package was not found - Ubuntu SDK default template has this error

Tags: unity, application-development, scopes

I want to do some Unity Scope development and I'm getting this error:

*CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
  A required package was not found*

Here's a quick video of how I'm creating my project: http://youtu.be/yfvNZrCf6mw

How can I fix this so that I can get a working (building) template to start working on?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running the SDK on? And are you using the SDK from the SDK team's PPA?

Comment: @dobey, I should have said: 14.04. The only PPA I'm using is to get g++ up to the version the SDK was complaining about. It was suggested elsewhere that I do my work on 14.10 instead, but if there's a PPA I can use to avoid that, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to build something that requires packages only available on 14.10, on 14.04.

You will need to build in 14.10. You can do this from the SDK by setting up an appropriate kit for building your package, and it will create a chroot of 14.10 to build the package for a phone.

Comment: Thanks dobey. I'll try on 14.10 and accept this answer based on that. Does that mean the SDK IDE is less than useful on 14.04 or is it just for a subset of applications/targets that it's broken for?

Comment: It works fine on 14.04, but depending on what you are developing, you may not be able to build and run directly on 14.04. The build kits in the SDK take care of this by building in a chroot, where the newer dependencies are available.

Comment: Okay - but they don't take care of it for Unity Scope development?

Comment: Yes, but you need to configure the kit properly to build in the chroot. If you're getting that error from a build _inside_ a 14.10 chroot kit in the SDK, then it may not be installing the build deps for the scope project type in the chroot.